# Django Form - toggle field existence dynamically

Tags: python, django, race-condition

**Python 2.7.8 and Django==1.4.2 (Legacy app)**

I came across a confusing issue a few months ago when investigating a bug in a Django project. I believe it's related to how Django pools threads, but it's really hard to pin down. Here's a minimal viable example to reproduce this issue:

```
class FormA(Form):
    field_a = CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['initial']['test']:
            self.base_fields['field_b'] = CharField()
        super(FormA, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class ViewA(FormView):
    template_name = 'test'
    form_class = FormA

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(ViewA, self).get_initial()
        initial['test'] = self.request.GET.get('test')
```

When adding a new field dynamically based on the query param, if a request with the query param **test** evaluating to True is made first, **field_b** will be included on FormA. But, I suspect that for all consecutive requests (even if **test** evaluates to False), FormA retains **field_b**.

The fix for this is to pop or delete **field_b** from self.base_fields and then evaluate the test variable. This works, but I'm not completely sure why it's needed.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.base_fields.pop('field_b', 0)
    if kwargs['initial']['test']:
        self.base_fields['field_b'] = CharField()
    super(FormA, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

It seems like, the base_fields dict is persisting across multiple requests. So this raises the following:

1) Why is the base_fields dict not getting re-initialized on each request?

2) Is there a better solution to solve this issue instead of performing pop/del on base_fields?

3) If there is no other solution, does pop/del lead to a race condition? What if both of the requests are made at the same time--- is one request going to mess up the base_fields for the other request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-1.4/blob/1.4-nonrel/django/forms/forms.py#L90), you should not modify the `base_fields` of the instance.

**Solution**:

```
class FormA(Form):
    field_a = CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # this will populate `self.fields`
        super(FormA, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if kwargs['initial']['test']:
            self.fields['field_b'] = CharField()
```